# Is circular reference with Typescript array properties bad design?

Tags: object-oriented-design, typescript, circular-dependency

I understand that having circular dependency can be bad design. However, I have a question regarding a certain class structure.

As an example:

ocean.ts

```
import {Boat} from './boat';

export class Ocean {
    boats: Array<Boat> = [];

    getWaterLevel() {
        return 5;
    }

    createBoats() {
        for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            const boat = new Boat();
            boat.ocean = this;
            boat.engineRunning = true;

            this.boats.push(boat);
        }
    }
}
```

boat.ts

```
import {Ocean} from './ocean';

export class Boat {
    engineRunning: boolean;
    ocean: Ocean;

    canMove() {
        return this.ocean.getWaterLevel() > 5 && this.engineRunning;
    }
}
```

In Typescript this can't be done without a circular reference problem from the imports. I've also read people conclude that its a sign of bad design. The only other solution I could see is to create a third layer which is something like OceanBoat and manage the two resources. Is this bad design or a bad limitation of Typescript? Are there any better solutions for handling this without merging files into one or creating a abstract layer like "OceanBoat"? Is there anything like require_once() for Typescript?

Comment: Compared to some other language such as Java, this is a limitation but other languages also don't allow this.  Whether it's a 'bad' limitation is a subjective question.

Comment: I understand the benefit of enforcing this in a A to B / B to A scenario. But in a situation where the parent has a list of children and the children knows about its parent, I see it as a bad limitation.

Comment: Do you want options for solving this problem?  Right now the way you have put it, it's a yes/no question.  I suggest editing it if you want help with the solution.

Comment: Fair enough, looking to see if there is a eloquent solution.

Answer (score 3):

Your situation is actually language agnostic and I would consider it to be a bad design in any programming language.

The problems with circular references generally include the chicken&egg problem, because when you want to instantiate an object you do not know which you should instantiate first. Should you instantiate an ocean? But then you have to also provide boats, which require the ocean? It's a closed circle.

Without introducing a third layer, this problem can be easily solved by only referencing objects by their identities, and instead of having a direct dependency on a big object as a part of constructor, methods will accept such object when needed.

So, instead of depending on an `Ocean` instance, a `Boat` would depend on an `oceanId`. But because you need the ocean to check the water level, you would pass an `Ocean` instance to the `canMove` method:

```
import {Ocean} from './ocean';

export class Boat {
    engineRunning: boolean;
    oceanId: OceanId;

    canMove(ocean: Ocean) {
        OceanId oId = ocean.Id();

        if (!this.oceanId.equals(oId)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Passed ocean does not match boat ocean.");
        }

        return ocean.getWaterLevel() > 5 && this.engineRunning;
    }
}
```

If necessary, you could then refactor the code even further by adding a logical method on the `Ocean`, that way you could implement a pattern similar to double-dispatch, adding a property to configure required water level for a boat which would be used to determine whether a given ocean has such water level or does not:

```
export class Ocean {

    hasWaterLevelAbove(waterLevelToCheck: int) {
        return 5 > waterLevelToCheck;
    }
}

export class Boat {
    requiredWaterLevel: int;
    engineRunning: boolean;
    oceanId: OceanId;

    canMove(ocean: Ocean) {
        OceanId oId = ocean.Id();

        if (!this.oceanId.equals(oId)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Passed ocean does not match boat ocean.");
        }

        return ocean.hasWaterLevelAbove(this.requiredWaterLevel) && this.engineRunning;
    }
}
```

---

> I would argue this isn't the chicken or the egg problem. A ocean
>   doesn't have to be created for a boat but a ocean has to be created
>   for a boat. Does it not seem redundant to pass through a variable
>   ocean when you intend your boat to be in only one ocean at a time? If
>   it changes ocean, you would change it within its property, that makes
>   real world sense.
>
> And even then, a boat doesn't have to have an ocean. It could be being
>   built at the moment.

When you persist an ocean, I can imagine you could have a method name e.g. `loadOcean`, loading the ocean from the database. How are you planning to create an instance of an ocean with all its boats which require an instance of the ocean? Sure, you could create an empty ocean object, assign its reference to the boats, modify the ocean reference later on by assigning it other properties and finally also assign to the reference the boats. But this is not a very nice approach.

And when you do persist a boat and want to work somewhere with a single boat, you would have a `loadBoatById` method to fetch a persisted boat, but only to fetch a single boat you would need to fetch the entire instance of the ocean the boat is associated with which would then force you to fetch all the boats in the ocean (because of your design) causing an unnecessary memory overhead.

> Whats even more funny is this would still cause a circular dependency
>   problem because you've type scripted the ocean variable causing the
>   import on boat.ts.

Circular dependencies are not created by importing libraries in a circle. They're created by misusing the imported libraries. Having a `boat.ts` import `Ocean` and `ocean.ts` import `Boat` in the way I've described is perfectly fine and shouldn't be any problem for any modern compiler.

E.g. in C++, you don't even have to import anything, simply putting the following structure should fail during compilation because it's impossible to determine the necessary stack size on compile-time for the application to even execute (because A needs B which needs A which needs B,...):

```
class A {
private:
    B b;
}

class B {
private:
    A a;
}
```

Surprisingly, the following would compile in C++ (since you would know the size of a pointer at compile time) but would still be considered a bad design:

```
class A {
private:
    B *b;
}

class B {
private:
    A *a;
}
```

Comment: I would argue this isn't the chicken or the egg problem. A ocean doesn't have to be created for a boat but a ocean has to be created for a boat. Does it not seem redundant to pass through a variable ocean when you intend your boat to be in only one ocean at a time? If it changes ocean, you would change it within its property, that makes real world sense.

Comment: And even then, a boat doesn't have to have an ocean. It could be being built at the moment.

Comment: Whats even more funny is this would still cause a circular dependency problem because you've type scripted the ocean variable causing the import on boat.ts.

Comment: @Abstract I have answered your comments in the question.

Comment: How do we move to a chat? Your examples while I appreciate them, appear to make a case that very simple things that are done eloquently in other languages are a very bad idea. You would instantiate the ocean first, then load in your boats. This is how OOP works. Your comment on, "what if theres only one boat, memory overhead" That doesn't matter because in the way you're providing as a solution you would still need an ocean which would be the same memory usage. You wouldn't have to fetch all boats to use the ocean for a single boat.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would typically go about this is to use an interface.  I'm not familiar with TypeScript but it supports [interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html).  It also seems duck typing might be an option but either way the result is the same.

To resolve the circular dependency, I would remove the tight coupling from `Boat` to `Ocean` at the very least.  For example you could create an interface called `BodyOfWater` or whatever makes sense.  Then Boat doesn't need to know about Ocean and you can also come up with other bodies such as lakes and rivers.

You could do something similar for Boat and create an interface called `Vehicle` but this isn't necessary to solve the specific problem at hand.

Here's my best attempt at an example (I don't know typescript.)

## bodyofwater.ts

```
interface BodyOfWater {
    getWaterLevel(): number;
}
```

## ocean.ts

```
import {Boat} from './boat';
import {BodyOfWater} from './bodyofwater';

export class Ocean implements BodyOfWater {
    boats: Array<Boat> = [];

    getWaterLevel() {
        return 5;
    }

    createBoats() {
        for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            const boat = new Boat();
            boat.bodyofwater = this;
            boat.engineRunning = true;

            this.boats.push(boat);
        }
    }
}
```

## boat.ts

```
import {BodyOfWater} from './bodyofwater';

export class Boat {
    engineRunning: boolean;
    bodyofwater: BodyOfWater;

    canMove() {
        return this.bodyofwater.getWaterLevel() > 5 && this.engineRunning;
    }
}
```

Comment: you'll still have the circular reference problem with interfaces because you'll have to import that interface into your class which would have the imports of the classes you were trying to avoid.

Comment: I think what you're calling for is adding an abstract layer/middleman class which is really only there because of this circular dependency issue. That would work, however doesn't seem optimal.

Comment: I don't follow.  "which would have the imports of the classes"  What would have these?  The interface?  If so, that is not the case.

Comment: import {OceanInterface} from './ocean-interface'; class Ocean implements OceanInterface

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: Also, I would recommend against things like `OceanInterface`.  You should think in more abstract terms when defining an interface.

Comment: If you implement the interface onto the class, you will have a deeper level of circular dependency. boat implements boat-interface, boat-interface imports ocean, ocean implements ocean-interface, ocean-interface imports boat.

Comment: @Abstract: The idea behind using an interface to break circular dependencies is that `ocean-interface` *does not* import `boat`. Both ` boat` and `ocean` would import `ocean-interface`.

Comment: Well if the idea is for both classes to not know about each other, why even use an interface? The point of the interface bypass would be so I can still use boat within an ocean and an ocean within a boat.

Comment: "Well if the idea is for both classes to not know about each other, why even use an interface?"  Because the interface is what allows the two classes to not know about each other.  That's kind of the whole point.

Comment: Can you show me an example using Typescript with the interfaces? From what I understand you'd still have to define the properties within the class even if it extends the interfaces. The interfaces don't store any logic of interaction, they're just simple boil plates for the classes expectations.

Comment: @Abstract I added an example.

Comment: @Abstract Just fixed a bug that might be crucial to understanding.

Comment: What you have looks fairly solid to me now.

Comment: So, I appreciate the example and do see what you're saying. I feel however this isn't an eloquent solution, rather a hack to solve a problem that shouldn't even exist. I don't see how this is better design, we're essentially creating unnecessary layers to bypass what in a real world sense works. A boat can be in a ocean, an ocean has many boats. Abstracting a body of water would make sense perhaps if their were lakes, puddles and oceans. Then ocean would be a child of bodyofwater and then use polymorphism for boat's ocean reference. ocean: BodyOfWater, Ocean extends BodyOfWater.

Comment: Is there something I am fundamentally wrong about and should consider this curse of non circular references as a blessing? I've seen other languages handle circular references eloquently and effectively, I don't feel convinced of its benefits and see it as a limitation.

Comment: @Abstract I would argue that this is a better design in general.  If all you ever need is this simple relationship, I guess you could frame this as unnecessary but in anything beyond such a trivial example, using interfaces this way will tend to greatly improve the quality of your code.  You can now create a River, Lake, Swamp, Lagoon, etc. and your Boat class doesn't need to change.  As far as whether this is a language limitation, I think the answer is 'yes' but making this kind of this work is extra work on the language designer.  They apparently didn't think it was worth the trouble.

Comment: I understand the convention. But in a project that's very relationship heavy, there are a lot of instances where its just a simple relationship (e.g pivots, 1:1) nothing more, nothing less. Ultimately you can just say, well do it this way because in the event you ever need a higher level of grouped abstraction its already there. But now you're doing things just because, and not on demand. It also not a problem if you do this once, but it starts to really add bloat when the project is big and complex. I have many instances where relationships are at the level of complexity like ocean/boat.

Comment: @Abstract I feel like you are forgetting one very crucial thing. Objects in programming rarely completely reflect the nature of the objects in the real world. In programming you compromise and go ways that probably do not make complete sense in the real world but are better solutions in the programming world.

Comment: I understand that sometimes OOP has to resort to doing things very abstract, not real world related. (e.g 'AbstractNode') I would say though many situations( one above ) shouldn't require things outside of real world understanding. OOP doesn't have to reflect the real world all the time sure, but should be encouraged. Even doing it the proposed way, BodyOfWater, Lake, River, Ocean, Boat is real world oriented. The answer for this forced convention was kinda concluded as these type of situations are trivial and don't really exist in the serious programming world, but they do in my opinion.